# React Redux: how to abort a dispatch?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-thunk

I'm working with a SPA that it's like an email client: list of items on the left and open message on the right.

To fetch those 'messages' I'm making an API call thru an action creator.

The problem is when you click around on the list sometimes the API takes longer to fetch a message than others. So you could see a message selected on the left but its details on the right being from another one.

A workaround I thought was comparing the id from the list selected one with the returned from the API. But that requires an API update as well.

How should I solve it? Is there a way to cancel a dispatch when the same action is called, so I don't read wrong data?

Thanks!

Comment: You can use a cancel-able Promise library, so that you can cancel previous request when click a new message. A better approach is to use [`redux-saga`](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga)

Comment: Comparing the ID of the returned message with the ID of the selected one sounds perfectly fine. Why does it require an API change? (I guess you could even figure the ID out of the URL)

Comment: https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios - This library provides cancel-able Promises. I'd recommend you have a look at this :)